# How to create a train/test split of time-series data by year?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, cross-validation

I want to cross-validate my time-series data and split by the year of the timestamp.

Here is the following data in a pandas dataframe:

```
mock_data

timestamp             counts
'2015-01-01 03:45:14' 4
     .
     .
     .
'2016-01-01 13:02:14' 12
     .
     .
     .
'2017-01-01 09:56:54' 6
     .
     .
     .
'2018-01-01 13:02:14' 8
     .
     .
     .
'2019-01-01 11:39:40' 24
     .
     .
     .
'2020-01-01 04:02:03' 30

mock_data.dtypes
timestamp object
counts    int64
```

Looking into the [`TimeSeriesSplit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) function of scikit-learn, it does not appear that you can specify the `n_split` part by year. Is there another way that one can create successive training sets that result in the following train-test split?

```
tscv = newTimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5, by='year')
>>> print(tscv)  
newTimeSeriesSplit(max_train_size=None, n_splits=5, by='year')
>>> for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(mock_data):
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [2015] TEST: [2016]
TRAIN: [2015 2016] TEST: [2017]
TRAIN: [2015 2016 2017] TEST: [2018]
TRAIN: [2015 2016 2017 2018] TEST: [2019]
TRAIN: [2015 2016 2017 2018 2019] TEST: [2020]
```

Thanks for viewing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Updated Response

**Generic approach for data with arbitrary number of points in each year.**

First, some data with a few years of data with differing numbers of points in each, per the example. This is similar in approach to the original answer.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ts_2015 = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', periods=4).to_series()
ts_2016 = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31', periods=12).to_series()
ts_2017 = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31', periods=6).to_series()
ts_2018 = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', periods=8).to_series()
ts_2019 = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31', periods=24).to_series()
ts_2020 = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', periods=30).to_series()
ts_all = pd.concat([ts_2015, ts_2016, ts_2017, ts_2018, ts_2019, ts_2020])

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=ts_all.shape), 
                   'Y': np.random.randint(100, 200, size=ts_all.shape)},
                 index=ts_all)
df['year'] = df.index.year
df = df.reset_index()
```

Now we create a list of the unique years to iterate over and a dict to store the various split dataframes.

```py
year_list = df['year'].unique().tolist()
splits = {'train': [], 'test': []}

for idx, yr in enumerate(year_list[:-1]):
    train_yr = year_list[:idx+1]
    test_yr = [year_list[idx+1]]
    print('TRAIN: ', train_yr, 'TEST: ',test_yr)
    
    splits['train'].append(df.loc[df.year.isin(train_yr), :])
    splits['test'].append(df.loc[df.year.isin(test_yr), :])
```

Result:

```py
TRAIN:  [2015] TEST:  [2016]
TRAIN:  [2015, 2016] TEST:  [2017]
TRAIN:  [2015, 2016, 2017] TEST:  [2018]
TRAIN:  [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018] TEST:  [2019]
TRAIN:  [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019] TEST:  [2020]
```

The split dataframes would look something like the following:

```py
>>> splits['train'][0]

                index   X    Y  year
0 2015-01-01 00:00:00  20  127  2015
1 2015-05-02 08:00:00  25  197  2015
2 2015-08-31 16:00:00  61  185  2015
3 2015-12-31 00:00:00  75  144  2015
```

### Original Response

**It was pointed out to me that this approach would not work because it assumes that each year contains the same number of records.**

Your intent is a little unclear, but I believe you want to do is to pass a *dataframe* with a *timestamp index* into a new version of the `TimeSeriesSplit` class that will yield `n_split = n_years - 1` based on the number of years in your data. The `TimeSeriesSplit` class gives you the flexibility to do this, but you need to extract the year from your timestamp index first. The result doesn't quite look like what you've proposed, but the outcome is, I believe, what you want.

First some dummy data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
    
ts_index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2020-12-31',freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=ts_index.shape), 
                   'Y': np.random.randint(100, 200, size=ts_index.shape)},
                 index=ts_index)
```

Now a year for the `TimeSeriesSplit` to work on. Because we have to index into this thing by row number and `pd.ix` is deprecated, I reset the index from timestamp to numerical:

```py
df['year'] = df.index.year
df = df.reset_index()
```

And then a `TimeSeriesSplit` instance with the correct number of splits (`n_years - 1`):

```py
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=len(df['year'].unique()) - 1)
```

Now we can generate the indices. Instead of printing the indices, print the year column that corresponds and only print the unique years:

```py
for train_idx, test_idx in tscv.split(df['year']):
    print('TRAIN: ', df.loc[df.index.isin(train_idx), 'year'].unique(), 
          'TEST: ', df.loc[df.index.isin(test_idx), 'year'].unique())
```

```
TRAIN:  [2015] TEST:  [2016]
TRAIN:  [2015 2016] TEST:  [2017]
TRAIN:  [2015 2016 2017] TEST:  [2018]
TRAIN:  [2015 2016 2017 2018] TEST:  [2019]
TRAIN:  [2015 2016 2017 2018 2019] TEST:  [2020]
```

You would of course access your training/test sets in a similar manner. If you really wanted to button this up nicely, you could extend the `TimeSeriesSplit` class and either customize the initialization or add some new methods.

Comment: Thanks @mayosten, I think this is really close. However, when I try to run this against my own dataset, the years in the test set are overlapped. This is because the amount of data in each year is uneven. For instance, running numpy's `random.randint` always produces a dataframe with equal amounts of data within each year, whereas the "real" data has different amounts every year. My output ends up looking like:
    TRAIN: [2015] TEST: [2016]  
    TRAIN:  [2016] TEST:  [2016 2017]  
    TRAIN:  [2016 2017] TEST:  [2017 2018]
    TRAIN:  [2016 2017 2018] TEST:  [2018 2019 2020]

Comment: @Sepa I see now, and I see why the answer provided before wouldn't work. I think you might need a custom function in this case, but it shouldn't be too far off from what is already there. You would use the years extracted from the date time to build a list of unique years, then iterate through them up to year `n-1` to harvest your test and training sets, indexing into the df using `df.loc[df.years < test_year,:]` for your training set. Does that make sense or would it be useful to modify my earlier response?

Comment: This makes sense, is it possible for you to modify the earlier response to reflect what you are referring to? Your answer will be more permanent than these comments below.

Comment: @Sepa now modified to more generically handle the differing number of records across years. I think this is what you were going for?

Comment: Nice! I tried this on my "real" and it prints as expected. I believe I have an older version of pandas (0.20.3) that's not creating the random data and leaves a "ValueError: Must specify two of start, end, or periods". I'll try actually performing a train/test now, but this solves the question I asked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, glad this helps.