# How to train with TimeSeriesSplit from sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, classification, grid-search

I have this kind of data (columns):

```
| year-month | client_id | Y | X1.. Xn |
```

Where `Y` is if the client `client_id` purchased the product in a given `year-month`. And `X` are the explanatory variables. I have two years of monthly data, and I have done the split correctly with `TimeSeriesSplit()` given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069691/how-to-create-a-train-test-split-of-time-series-data-by-year) answer. The problem now, is that I'm looking to do a `GridSearchCV()` on that split, trying different models (`RF`, `XGBoostClassifier()`, `LightGBM()`, etc.) with different hyperparameters, but I can't figure out a way to use the `GridSearchCV()` with the split done.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please let me know if the answer is correct? otherwise, I will try to revise it to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `splits` df based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58072774/1076264) question.
First save indices for each Fold into arrays of tuples (train,test), i.e,:

```py
 [(train_indices, test_indices), # 1stfold
  (train_indices, test_indices)] # 2nd fold etc
```

The following code will do this:

```py
custom_cv = []

for FOLD_train,FOLD_test in zip(splits['train'],splits['test']):
    custom_cv.append((np.array(FOLD_train.index.values.tolist()),np.array(FOLD_test.index.values.tolist())))
```

you can use `GridSearchCV()` in the following manner:

Here we create dictionary with classifier functions and another dictionary with param list

This is just a sample make sure to limit search space when testing,

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
dict_classifiers = {

    "Random Forest": RandomForestClassifier(),
    "Gradient Boosting Classifier": GradientBoostingClassifier(),
    "Linear SVM": SVC(),
    "XGB": XGBRegressor(),
    "Logistic Regression": LogisticRegression(),
    "Nearest Neighbors": KNeighborsClassifier(),
    "Decision Tree": DecisionTreeClassifier(),
}

params = {
    "Random Forest": {"max_depth": range(5, 30, 5), "min_samples_leaf": range(1, 30, 2),
                      "n_estimators": range(100, 2000, 200)},

    "Gradient Boosting Classifier": {"learning_rate": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1], "n_estimators": range(1000, 3000, 200)},
    "Linear SVM": {"kernel": ["rbf", "poly"], "gamma": ["auto", "scale"], "degree": range(1, 6, 1)},
    "XGB": {'min_child_weight': [1, 5, 10],
            'gamma': [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5],
            'subsample': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
            'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
            'max_depth': [3, 4, 5], "n_estimators": [300, 600],
            "learning_rate": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
            },
    "Logistic Regression": {'penalty': ['none', 'l2'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]},
    "Nearest Neighbors": {'n_neighbors': [3, 5, 11, 19], 'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'], 'metric': ['euclidean', 'manhattan']},
    "Decision Tree": {'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 'max_depth': np.arange(3, 15)},

}


for classifier_name in dict_classifiers.keys() & params:

    print("training: ", classifier_name)
    gridSearch = GridSearchCV(
        estimator=dict_classifiers[classifier_name], param_grid=params[classifier_name], cv=custom_cv)
    gridSearch.fit(df[['X']].to_numpy(), # shoud have shape of (n_samples, n_features) 
                   df[['Y']].to_numpy().reshape((-1))) #this should be an array with shape (n_samples,)
    print(gridSearch.best_score_, gridSearch.best_params_)
```

replace `['X']` with `df.columns[pd.Series(df.columns).str.startswith('X')]` on `gridsearch.fit`, if you want to pass in all columns starting with `'X'` in their name (e.g., `'X1'`,`'X2'`, ...) as train_set.

Comment: I'm trying to get it work, but it shows me this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'X'` I think is because you are assuming that the X is only one column when are actually plenty of them. I tried to solve it replacing `np.array(df.X.tolist())` with `np.array(df[X_cols]tolist())` where `X_cols = X.columns` with `X` as a dataframe with the independent columns already processed, but it tells me that `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`. What are you trying to do there? Transforming the dataframe to a list to transform it to a matrix?

Comment: @Chris I updated the answer with modified arguments on `gridsearch.fit`, basically you can either replace `'X'` with `'X1'`, `'X2'`, ... to pass multiple ones or use `df.columns[pd.Series(df.columns).str.startswith('X')]` to pull in anything starts with `'X'` in column names.

Comment: @Chris Did you get a chance to try this?

Comment: It worked! Can you explain it in order to understand why it worked? Specifically, the `custom_cv` construction, the logic behind using `.to_numpy()` and `reshape((-1))` in `gridSearch.fit()`. And, I would appreciate it, your personal opinion on this approach to build a model :) Thanks!

Comment: `custom_CV` is just a try to arrange each fold indices in a way that gridsearchCV needs i.e. iterable list of tuples of (train, test), check the fourth item of cv parameter on documentation [An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). the Same thing applies to rest i.e., check the parameters `X` and `y` of `fit` they need an array of `(n_samples,n_features)`, and `(n_samples,)` t work. so, `.to_numpy()` convert list to NumPy array, and `reshape((-1))` is ... @Chris

Comment: making it form `(n_samples,1)`to `(n_samples,)`. about the opinion, you can optimize hyperparameters using this approach if your sets are enough small that the whole optimization takes reasonable time! otherwise, you can go with the train/test/dev set approach. which model to choose totally depends on your data, if you have too many client_ids, then you should consider other approaches ..... but I think you shouldn't expect, too much increase in final accuracy with just HPO, consider data-centric approach if possible, you might get better results by cleaning data rather than HPO. @Chris